# I do not receive changes to onChange when inserting data into the database

Tags: android, mvvm, kotlin, android-livedata

I'm trying to write applications with mvvm architecture. But I do not receive changes in onChange when I insert data into a database. The logic that I want to achieve: Go to the cache, take the data. Then we go to the server and receive data. If there are changes, update both the cache and ui. Tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
class PageFragment : BaseFragment() {

    private val pageName= "fly"

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

        ...

        val viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(PageViewModel(activity!!.appliacation)::class.java)

        viewModel.getPages().observe(this, Observer<Page> { page ->
            adapter.contents = page!!.content

        })
        viewModel.pageName = pageName

        return view
    }
}
```

ViewModel class

```
class PageViewModel constructor(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {
    private var repository: Repository = Repository(application)

    private var mutablePages = MutableLiveData<Page>()
    fun getPages(): LiveData<Page> = mutablePages

    var pageName: String = ""
        set(value) {
            field = value
            loadData(value)
        }

    private fun loadData(pageName: String) {
        GlobalScope.launch {
            withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                mutablePages.value = repository.getPage(pageName)
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Repository class

```
class Repository(context: Context) {

private var dbRepository: DbRepository = DbRepository(context)

....

suspend fun getPage(pageName: String): Page =
            dbRepository.getPage(pageName).let { pagesMapper.dbToBusinessEntity(it) }.also {
//get data from the server and put it into db
//data from the server put into db successful. By this I will not write how I do it. 
                GlobalScope.launch { updatePage(pageName) }
            }

....

    }
```

DbRepository class

```
class DbRepository(context: Context) {

private var pagesDao: pagesDao = AppDatabase.getInstance(context).pagesDao()

....

suspend fun getpage(pageName: String): PageDb =
            GlobalScope.async { pagesDao.getPage(pageName) }.await()

....

}
```

Dao class

```
@Dao
interface PagesDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM pages WHERE pageName= :pageName")
    fun getPage(pageName: String): PageDb

}
```

Entity data class

```
@Entity(tableName = "pages")
data class PageDb(

        var content: List<Any>,
        @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = false)
        var pageName: String

)
```

I would also like to hear criticism of this code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Found what the problem was ...
In order for LiveData to be notified of data changes, the method for retrieving data from the database should not have the suspend keyword.